# Is there a Kibana equivalent for Vespa Search?

Tags: vespa

I want to be able to quickly make index, modify schema, feed test data, delete data, copy/clone index, run queries on the index from the web interface - just like I can do with Elasticsearch. Is there such tooling available? If not is it in plans?

I tried Vespa CLI - while it's handy, it is not feature complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/tree/master/client/js/app has a GUI for the query API. https://cloud.vespa.ai/en/cloning-applications-and-data covers cloning.

Schema development is easy using the https://docs.vespa.ai/en/schemas.html#intellij-plugin - as Vespa is built for safe deployments, a "deploy" must be done to activate schema changes, this is a simple and fail-safe workflow (and incompatible changes will emit a warning a stop the deployment)

Comment: Thanks! Does Query Builder / GUI for the query API - come predeployed for Vespa Cloud users? Or if installed locally, can it be used against the Vespa cloud application instance?

Comment: We are working on that, not ready yet (must handle the security credentials), track blog.vespa.ai for progress